# insert observable into another observable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, system.reactive

Assume [pseudo] code:

```
class MyActivity : Activity {

   Observable<string> mainObl

   void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      mainObl = Observable.Never<string>();
   }


   Disposable subscription;

   void OnStart() {
      subscription = mainObl.Subscribe(UpdateUiOnEvent);
   }

   void OnStop() {
      subscription.Dispose();
   }


   // on click - start filling existing Observable with data from another source
   void OnButtonClick() {
      var tmpObl = Observale.just(1,2,3,4);
      mainObl.WhatMethodHere(tmpObl); // <<<<<<<<<<<< see Q
   }

}
```

Ad Q:
Which method to use in above `WhatMethodHere` to hook tmpObl in mainOble.
Or how to start injecting into existing Observable data from another source [another observable]?

**=== update ===**
**warning: what is proposed in question is bad practice in Rx Android**

I asked this as beginning RX user
but answers correctly response to initial question

Answer (score 2):

The neatest way to do this is to keep everything in the Observable space rather than trying to mix event and observable code. Assuming your button is called "button1" you can achieve this with the following [pseudo] code:

```
class MyActivity : Activity {

   IDisposable subscription;

   void OnStart() {
      subscription = Observable
          // Adapt a delegate to the event signature and subscribe to the event (unsubscribing when subscription disposed)
          .FromEventPattern<EventHandler,EventArgs>(handler => (s,e) => handler(e), handler => button1.TouchUpInside += handler, handler => button1.TouchUpInside -= handler)               
          // Emit a new observable containing the data "from another source"
          .Select(args => Observable.Return("1", "2", "3", "4"))
          // Dispose any subscription to the previous observable and subscribe to the new observable emitted from above           
          .Switch()
          .Subscribe(UpdateUiOnEvent);
   }

   void OnStop() {
      subscription.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Rx just looks clean when done properly. Well done. One addition, the `IDisposable subscription` could be changed to a `SingleAssignmentDisposable` or `SerialDisposable` and then you wont get a NullRefEx in your `Dispose` method. Else check for null in the `Dispose` method.

Comment: You know that this doesn't compile? There's no overload of `.Return(...)` that takes a `param string[]`.

Comment: I did say it was pseudo code. Shouldn't be hard to correct.

Comment: @ibebbs - Fair enough. I didn't spot that. Perhaps a bit confusing to have everything else looking like valid C# code and then to have one line that's not.

Comment: It was my understanding that the OP used Observable.Return as a place holder for the actual observable which is why I copied it verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this if I were trying to keep your code in the same sort of structure that it is in now:

```
class MyActivity
{
    private Subject<IObservable<string>> mainObl;
    private IDisposable subscription = null;

    public void OnCreate()
    {
        mainObl = new Subject<IObservable<string>>();
    }

    public void OnStart()
    {
        subscription = mainObl.Merge().Subscribe(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        });
    }

    public void OnStop()
    {
        subscription.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        var tmpObl = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
            .Select(x => x.ToString())
            .ToObservable();
        mainObl.OnNext(tmpObl);
    }
}
```

Now when you call this:

```
var ma = new MyActivity();

ma.OnCreate();
ma.OnStart();
ma.OnButtonClick();
```

...you get this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: But then you have to ask, why is it a `Subject<IObservable<string>>` and not a `Subject<string[]>`. Which I then have to ask, why use a subject? It adds more code, adds one more place to forget to dispose (subject isn't disposed in this example), so while this provides a helpful stepping stone for the OP, the other answer is far better.

Comment: @LeeCampbell - The OP is specifically asking how to inject an observable into another one after the first is subscribed to - it can't be a `Subject<string[]>` in that case. The other answer doesn't even compile.

Comment: @LeeCampbell - Also, `OnButtonClick` may or may not actually be an event handler. It certainly doesn't have the right signature. I've answered this question taking all those things in to account and just provided the most direct answer I could.

Comment: The OP also states they're a beginner in RX so probably isn't aware how to pose the question of how to achieve desired behaviour correctly.

Comment: @ibebbs - Which is another reason why I went with a direct as possible answer here.